# Is it faster to use regular distance or squared distance?

Tags: square-root, vectormath

Is it faster to use the square root in a vector length / distance operation and then comparing to some value or is it faster to square the value that is compared and then don't use the square root? So basically in pseudo code, is this:

```
sqrt(x * x + y * y) > a
```

faster then this:

```
x * x + y * y > a * a
```

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the data, the platform, the runtime, the programming language, optimizations? When asking "which is fastest, A or B", your **best** option is to do performance profiling.

Comment: I take it your question is really "Which is fastest, taking the square root of a number, or multiplying a number by itself"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen well I don't think that much could be optimised here, the only thing that really could be different in different languages is the algorithm for square roots. Of course I could just test it on my own, but then everybody that has the same question also has to do it for them self...

Comment: But then if it might depend on the platform, runtime, language, etc, then everybody **must** do the same thing for themselves, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am showing this code , to let you know that how big is the square root function**

*Even though , we use an inbuild function , it has to go through these process*

**As you can see now , sqrt is a result of a looped function which has multiplication, division and addition**

*So if you do `x * x + y * y > a * a`*   it will take only lesser time than the sqrt method, which i can confirm with this.

```
sqrt(int n)
{

    float temp, sqrt;

    // store the half of the given number e.g from 256 => 128
    sqrt = n / 2;
    temp = 0;

    // Iterate until sqrt is different of temp, that is updated on the loop
    while(sqrt != temp){
        // initially 0, is updated with the initial value of 128
        // (on second iteration = 65)
        // and so on
        temp = sqrt;

        // Then, replace values (256 / 128 + 128 ) / 2 = 65
        // (on second iteration 34.46923076923077)
        // and so on
        sqrt = ( n/temp + temp) / 2;
    }

    printf("The square root of '%d' is '%f'", n, sqrt);
}
```